# AAS journal bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, aastex

I am using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[style=numeric,bibstyle=aasjournal]{biblatex}
\usepackage{aas_macros}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

To cite references as number within brackets in the text, but also print the bibliography as in the [AAS journal style](https://journals.aas.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/aasjournal.bst). I copied the `aasjournal.bst` (as well as the `aas_macros`) file in my main folder in overleaf but, when I compile, one of the errors I receive is:

```
Package biblatex Error: Style 'aasjournal' not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

`.bst` files are style files for BibTeX and are completely incompatible with `biblatex`. You have to choose between using `biblatex` or using your `.bst` file.

I assume you want to use `aasjournal.bst` because you want to submit to an AAS journal, so you have to stick with the `.bst` file and `biblatex` has to go.

Indeed the `aastex631` class available from https://journals.aas.org/aastex-package-for-manuscript-preparation/ is based on `revtex`, which loads `natbib` (`natbib` is incompatible with `biblatex`).

The example file `sample631.tex` provided there has the following bibliography setup

```
\documentclass[linenumbers]{aastex631}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{2013A&A...558A..33A}

\bibliography{sample631}
\bibliographystyle{aasjournal}
\end{document}
```

---

If you do not want to publish with the AAS class, but insist on using `aasjournal.bst` with numeric citations nonetheless, you can try the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\longestbiblabel}
\newlength{\runninglongestbiblabel}

\newcommand*{\abx@longestbiblabel}[1]{%
  \global\setlength{\longestbiblabel}{#1}}

\patchcmd\NAT@bibsetnum
  {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}}
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\longestbiblabel}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}}
  {}{}

\newcommand\pyser@setlabwidth[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\@biblabel{#2}}%
  \ifnum\@tempdima>#1%
    \global#1\@tempdima
  \fi
  \endgroup}

\renewcommand\NAT@wrout[5]{%
  \pyser@setlabwidth{\runninglongestbiblabel}{#1}%
  \if@filesw
    {\let\protect\noexpand\let~\relax
     \immediate\write\@auxout{%
       \string\bibcite{#5}{{#1}{#2}{{#3}}{{#4}}}}}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \if@filesw
     {\let\protect\noexpand\let~\relax
      \immediate
      \write\@auxout{%
        \string\abx@longestbiblabel{\the\runninglongestbiblabel}}}%
  \fi
  \ifdim\longestbiblabel=\runninglongestbiblabel
  \else
    \G@refundefinedtrue
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{article-full,incollection-full}

\bibliography{xampl}
\bibliographystyle{aasjournal}
\end{document}
```

[image: Numeric citations with AAS bib entries.]

This uses `natbib` with the `numbers` option together with `aasjournal`. Unfortunately, `aasjournal` is not a numeric style and thus does not calculate the longest label automatically. This makes the indentation in the numeric reference list look odd. So we patch that in manually by keeping track of the longest label ourselves.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately your assumption is not correct. Oherwise I would have used the `aastex` class and that was all. I need to compile a document with the specs I reported in the post, citations as numbers in brackets, references as in `aasjournal.bst`. But thank you for pointing me to the incompatibility of .bst and biblatex